# Infinite recursion when referring to pkgs.system from Nix module options section

Tags: nix, nixos, nixpkgs

The following is a minimal reproducer for an infinite recursion error when building a nixos configuration:

```hs
(import <nixpkgs/nixos>) {
  configuration = { pkgs, ... }: {
    options = builtins.trace "Building a system with system ${pkgs.system}" {};
  };
  system = "x86_64-linux";
}
```

When evaluated it fails as follows, unless the reference to `pkgs.system` is removed:

```
$ nix-build 
error: infinite recursion encountered

       at /Users/charles/.nix-defexpr/channels/nixpkgs/lib/modules.nix:496:28:

          495|         builtins.addErrorContext (context name)
          496|           (args.${name} or config._module.args.${name})
             |                            ^
          497|       ) (lib.functionArgs f);
```

If we look at the implementation of [`nixos/lib/eval-config.nix:33`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/a7a5b8d51352616add9849c8874d688e59a815ec/nixos/lib/eval-config.nix#L53), we see that the value passed for the `system` argument is set as an overridable default in `pkgs`. Does this mean we can't access it until later in the evaluation process?

(In the real-world use case, I'm introspecting a flake -- investigating `someFlake.packages.${pkgs.system}` to find packages for which to generate configuration options.)

This has been cross-posted to NixOS Discourse; see https://discourse.nixos.org/t/accessing-target-system-when-building-options-for-a-module/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the module system to construct the configuration, it needs to know which `config` and `options` items exist, at least to the degree necessary to produce the root attribute set of configuration.

The loop is as follows:

1. Evaluate the attribute names in `config`
2. Evaluate the attribute names of the `options`
3. Evaluate `pkgs` (your code)
4. Evaluate `config._module.args.pkgs` (definition of module argument)
5. Evaluate the attribute names in `config` (loop)

It can be broken by removing or reducing the dependency on `pkgs`.
For instance, you could define your "dynamic" options as `type = attrsOf foo` instead of enumerating the each item from your flake as individual options.

Another potential solution is to move the option definitions into a submodule. A submodule without `attrsOf` as in `attrsOf (submodule x)` is generally quite useless, but it may create a necessary indirection that separates your dynamic `pkgs`-dependent `options` from the module fixpoint that has `pkgs`.

```hs
(import <nixpkgs/nixos>) {
  configuration = { pkgs, lib, ... }: {
    options.foo = lib.mkOption {
      type = lib.types.submodule {
        options = builtins.trace "Building a system with system ${pkgs.system}" { };
      };
      default = { };
    };
  };
  system = "x86_64-linux";
}
```

```
nix-repl> config.foo
trace: Building a system with system x86_64-linux
{ }
```

Comment: Thank you -- this explains what was going on well enough to allow solid reasoning about the problem, which is really the thing I needed.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate approach for cases where avoiding recursion isn't feasible, one can use `specialArgs` in invoking `nixos/lib/eval-config.nix` to pass a final value not capable of being overridden through the module system:

```hs
let
  configuration = { pkgs, forcedSystem, ... }: {
    options = builtins.trace "Building a system with system ${forcedSystem}" {};
  };
in
(import <nixpkgs/nixos/lib/eval-config.nix>) {
  modules = [ configuration ];
  system = "x86_64-linux";
  specialArgs = { forcedSystem = "x86_64-linux"; };
}
```

Comment: Most usages of `specialArgs` are for module `imports`. `_module.args` has the benefit of being overridable and potentially mergeable.

Comment: @RobertHensing, indeed, but being overridable is exactly what makes `_module.args` unsuitable here; one gets the same infinite recursion when using it.

Comment: That is correct.